# Mock IConfiguration or IValueResolver

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

I am using automapper in my Program.cs like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfiles));
```

And in my MappingProfiles I have configured this profile:

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductToReturnDto>()
                .ForMember(d => d.ProductBrand, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ProductBrand.Name))
                .ForMember(d => d.ProductType, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ProductType.Name))
                .ForMember(d => d.PictureUrl, o => o.MapFrom<ProductUrlResolver>());
```

Im my ProductUrlResolver I get IConfiguration injected in the constructor and that IConfiguration is used in the ProductUrlResolver to get some properties from appsettings.*.json

Now I would like to write a XUnit test for my controller where i use MOQ to mock out the services and also I do this to create my mapper that normally get injected into my controller:

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cgf => cgf.AddProfile(new MappingProfiles()));
var mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfiguration);
```

But I get a error when the ProductUrlResolver is trying to get properties from the IConfiguration, and since I am not injecting the ProductUrlResolver into my MappingProfiles, but rather it is getting the ProductUrlResolver with the "o.MapFrom()" magic, then how do I trick the ProductUrlResolver to be able to get some data from some mocked or real configuration?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
public class MappingProfiles: Profile
{
    public MappingProfiles(IProductUrlResolver urlRes)
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductToReturnDto>()
                .ForMember(d => d.ProductBrand, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ProductBrand.Name))
                .ForMember(d => d.ProductType, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ProductType.Name))
                .ForMember(d => d.PictureUrl, o => o.ConvertUsing(new MyConverter(urlRes));
    }

    private class MyConverter: IValueConverter<string, string> { ... }
}
```

Now you can pass to the MappingProfiles either a normal or a mocked instance of your URL converter.
If you want a normal instance, don't use the whole configuration in it, use Options pattern:

```
 public class ProductUrlResolver : IProductUrlResolver {
       void ProductUrlResolver(IOptions<MySettings> settings) { ... }
    }
```

Than in your test you can instantiate it like this:

```
new ProductUrlResolver(Options.Create(new MySettings())
```